# JTextField calculate JButton Multiply and JButton Divide. Why is it not printing my results when clicking either button?

Tags: java, jbutton, jtextfield

I simply need to have two JTextFields that take in two numbers and when clicking the Multiply or Divide button it produces the answer. It looks good to me, but not good enough to work..  Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
 
 String result;
 
 JLabel introduction = new JLabel("Solve Math Problems");
 Font myFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
 JTextField jtNum1 = new JTextField(10);
 JTextField jtNum2 = new JTextField(10);
 JTextField jtResponse = new JTextField(10);
 
 JButton multiply = new JButton(" X ");
 JButton divide = new JButton(" / ");     
 
 JLabel answer = new JLabel("");
 final int WIDTH = 400;
 final int HEIGHT = 135;
 
 public Calculator(){
  super("My First Calculator");
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  
  introduction.setFont(myFont);
  answer.setFont(myFont);
  
  add(introduction);
  add(jtNum1);
  add(jtNum2);
  
  add(multiply);
  add(divide);      
  multiply.addActionListener(this);
  divide.addActionListener(this);
  
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
 }
 
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  
  int int1 = Integer.parseInt(jtNum1.getText());
        int int2 = Integer.parseInt(jtNum2.getText());
  
 
  if (e.getSource() == multiply) {
      jtResponse.setText(String.valueOf(int1*int2));
      } else if (e.getSource() == divide) {
         jtResponse.setText(String.valueOf(int1/int2));   
        
    
       System.out.println(jtResponse);  
    
  }  
 } 
}

public class CalculatorAction {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    Calculator frame = new Calculator();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 
 }
```

Comment: I am able to produce a window/ JFrame that has the two text fields with the buttons but does not do anything after entering the numbers and clicking either button.

Comment: you need to add your `jtResponse` to the frame which will show the result...

Comment: Add `add(jtResponse);` after the expression `add(divide);` thats the only change you need to make.

Comment: Please only use Runnable code snippets for HTML, CSS and JavaScript. This is written in java

Comment: Wooohooo!!! Awesome! That was it that you Reimeus,and svasa!  Now that I see it can someone tell me how to position the text fields in a better order?

Comment: @ScottD Do you want 2 rows, 1st row with two text fields, then the 2nd row holdingholding the buttons? If that is ok, I can post an answer to include this. Also, take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must add the action listener to the button.

jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

Comment: Each button has .addActionListener.  The question was answered answered on why I wasn't getting the results. Are you suggesting this would change my layout, as my latest comment?